# Sencha Touch 2 MVC - How to implement and use a custom proxy

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I've exactly the same problem from [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3119179/how-can-i-prevent-ext-js-from-including-an-entity-body-in-delete-requests-using?answertab=active#tab-top). However I'm using Sencha Touch 2 and I don't know how to actually use this custom store. I define my REST proxies inside the model classes. How would I access/use this custom proxy?

```
proxy: {
    type: 'rest',
    url: 'http://someUrl', 
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is fairly simple in Sencha Touch 2. This presumes you have an MVC architecture.

Firstly, you model - **app/model/Image.js**:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.Image', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    // Require your custom proxy
    requires: ['MyApp.proxy.MyCustomProxy'],

    config: {
        fields: ['name'],

        proxy: {
            // set the type of your proxy
            type: 'mycustomproxy'
        }
    }
});
```

And then define your proxy - **app/proxy/MyCustomProxy.js**:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.proxy.MyCustomProxy', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.proxy.Proxy',

    // Set your proxy alias
    alias: 'proxy.mycustomproxy',

    ...
});
```

Comment: Hey rdougan I am not able to display a list coming form a webservice.Here's link of that http://www.senchafiddle.com/#1AEdv 
It was running perfectly with local json file.Here's link of that http://www.senchafiddle.com/#b4K8w#rYgdP .Please provide me some solution here to display the list coming from webservice in xml format

Comment: Extermely important is adding prefix 'proxy' to alias, so you get 'proxy.mycustomproxy' in proxy define.
If not set loader will not recognize your class.