# HTTP DELETE request without body

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, http-delete

I am facing the same problem as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3119179/how-can-i-prevent-ext-js-from-including-an-entity-body-in-delete-requests-using): I am trying to connect my ExtJS 4.1 store with REST API, but when I delete the record from the store and consequently invoke HTTP DELETE method, it gets rejected by the server-side because the HTTP request that ExtJS sent contains body. Unfortunately, the accepted answer on the link above is not valid for version 4 of ExtJS and higher.

The best that I achieved so far is to send empty array (literally, [] ) as a body, but of course this is still rejected:

[image]

This is my code:

```
Ext.define('TT.proxy.CustomRestProxy', { 
    alias: 'proxy.customrestproxy', 
    extend: 'Ext.data.proxy.Rest', 

    buildRequest: function(operation) {

        var request = this.callParent(arguments);

        if(operation.action === 'destroy')
        {                                
            delete request.operation.records;
        }
        return request; 
    }
});

defineStore = function(storeName, modelName, url) {
    var storeProperties = {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
        requires: modelName,
        model: modelName,
        id: storeName,

        proxy: {
            type: 'customrestproxy',
            url: url,
            batchActions: false,
            noCache: false,
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },                
            reader: {
                type : 'json',
                totalProperty: 'total',
                successProperty: 'success',
                root: 'data'
            },
            writer: {
                type : 'json'
            },              
        }
    };

    Ext.define(storeName, storeProperties);
};
```

I would accept any answer that solves this issue, it does not have to include ExtJS-specific features, i.e. intercepting AJAX request or similar technique is also welcome.

Comment: Please don't start an edit war. Read the policies about tags in titles: http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a workaround based on AJAX interceptor, inspired by [this link](https://gist.github.com/suprememoocow/2823600). This  code solves the problem regardless of the framework used, so it can be also useful for other people who are not necessarily using Ext JS:

```
(function(XHR) {
    "use strict";

    var open = XHR.prototype.open;
    var send = XHR.prototype.send;
    var httpMethod;

    XHR.prototype.open = function(method, url, async, user, pass) {
        httpMethod = method;
        this._url = url;
        open.call(this, method, url, async, user, pass);
    };

    XHR.prototype.send = function(data) {
        if(httpMethod === 'DELETE')
        {
            data = null;            
        }        
        send.call(this, data);
    }
})(XMLHttpRequest);
```